# Support for Landscape orientation

Tags: ios, controller, orientation

I have an application which only supports portrait orientation, however, the requirement changed and requires the application to support for landscape orientation, I am in a total shock because I dont' know what to do, just in case do I have to redo all the xib's to support for landscape orientation?

Is there anyway, or an available technique of doing this?

TIA

mirage

Comment: It all depends but you need to give more information. I assume you're using .xib's or a storyboard? Are you able to use iOS6 or above to use autolayout? There are many ways to support all orientations.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with the InterfaceBuilder, CMD+Z is the solution but I hope that it isn't late .

If the problem is with the iOS 6, the solution is change your interface orientation method, you can google that .

If the problem is target info , just look at the summary

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how your layout is built. 
First you need to enable all orientations that you need to support and see how it'll looks like after autorotation - if something will be wrong then you can think what to do and how, but you have to post some more info.

To enable autorotation just edit/add proper methods in your controller:

```
// iOS >= 6.0
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

// iOS < 6.0
// that method is deprecated but you need that if you want to support iOS < 6.0
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```